# checkinstall + symbolic links

Tags: deb, symbolic-link, checkinstall

I am trying to package [this code](https://github.com/GENIVI/dlt-daemon/tree/v2.17.0) with checkinstall, but run into [this bug](https://bugtrack.izto.org:4442/show_bug.cgi?id=65) which prevents all the symbolic links for shared libraries to be created.

make install creates these links:

```
libdlt.so -> libdlt.so.2.17.0
libdlt.so.2 -> libdlt.so.2.17.0
```

The checkinstall package creates none of these, but ldconfig restores:

```
libdlt.so.2 -> libdlt.so.2.17.0
```

How do I make sure all the links are created? Or is there an alternative to checkinstall that I should use instead?

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that I called `make install` before `checkinstall`. Of course that installed all the stuff, and lead to checkinstall not correctly identifying which files need to be installed.